# Batch if exist with args in a loop

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I am trying to move differents files into specific folder through a loop. 
For each file, I set modalite, serie_no and serie_name and want to create a specific folder based on those attributes. The file will be also moved to this folder.

But the `IF EXIST` command fail (The syntax is not correct).

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "arg1=%~1"
cd /d D:\!arg1!

for /r %%i in (*.*) do (

REM ...
REM stuff to set modalite, serie_no and serie_name
REM ...

if exist D:\!arg1!\!modalite!(
cd D:\!arg1!\!modalite!
) else (
mkdir D:\!arg1!\!modalite!
cd D:\!arg1!\!modalite!
)

if exist D:\!arg1!\!modalite!\!serie_no!_!serie_name!(
move %%i D:\!arg1!\!modalite!\!serie_no!_!serie_name!
) else (
mkdir D:\!arg1!\!modalite!\!serie_no!_!serie_name!
move %%i D:\!arg1!\!modalite!\!serie_no!_!serie_name!
)

)
```

I tried to use `"modalite"`,`"serie_no"` and `"serie_name"` but still have the error

Can I use the `if exist` command in a for loop in that way? Or should I use `for /f %%a in () do ()`?

Or maybe there is another way to proceed? I am open to everything.

Comment: Add a space before `(` in both `if` statements

Comment: @wOxxOm If you add an answer to my question instead of this comment. I will accept yours in priority

Comment: Nah, I deem this a `typo`-kind of question and voted to close it for that reason.

Comment: In many cases, removing `@echo off` will make the problem obvious.